# zend date and summertime

Tags: zend-framework, zend-date

I have a issue with dates crossing from winter/summer time.. please see example

```
        $pickUpDate = '2011-10-23';
        $dropOffDate = '2011-10-31';
        $pickUpTime = '09:00';
        $dropOffTime = '09:00';

        Zend_Date::setOptions(array('fix_dst' => false));
        Zend_Date::setOptions(array('fix_dst' => false));
        $pickUpDateTime = new Zend_Date ( $pickUpDate);
        $pickUpDateTime->setTime ( $pickUpTime );
        $dropOffDateTime = new Zend_Date ( $dropOffDate);
        $dropOffDateTime->setTime ( $dropOffTime );


        $dateDiff = ceil(($dropOffDateTime->getTimestamp ( ) - $pickUpDateTime->getTimestamp ( )) / (3600 * 24));
        echo $dateDiff;
```

Echo produces 9... My Timezone is London, but I thought the fix_dst should fix the summertime issue? I have also tried to set timezone to GMT and UTC but has the same effect? any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Timestamps do not have Timezone information. You should avoid using them for this use case.

May be you should try with [Zend_Date::sub](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.date.overview.html) method between your 2 dates. This will take care of DST.

Please also review your timezone because from what I read from the link above :

> If your actual timezone within the
>   instance of Zend_Date is set to UTC or
>   GMT the option 'fix_dst' will not be
>   used because these two timezones do
>   not work with DST.